# Postgres - Optimise get all rows where as_at_date is the EOM

Tags: sql, postgresql, amazon-aurora

I have a table (postgres aurora) with 72 million rows, roughly 100k rows for each `as_at_date`.

I want to be able to select all data that has `as_at_date` value that is the end of the month. Eg. 30/4/2018, 31/12/2019, etc and return all 100k * N rows.

I actually have this working with the following query;

```
SELECT * 
FROM schema.table
WHERE as_at_date >= '2019-07-01' 
AND as_at_date IN 
(
SELECT max(as_at_date) 
FROM schema.table
GROUP BY date_part('month', as_at_date), date_part('year', as_at_date)
)
```

However the inner select just to get the max as_at_dates list for the outer select statement is taking 95%+ of the execution time (roughly 30s out of 31s).

Is there a more optimal way to get the month end as_at_dates to speed this up?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method is:

```
where extract(day from as_at_date + interval '1 day') = 1
```

That is, the last day of any month has the property that the next day is the first day of a month.